# How to change the color of a rectangle which is inside a button in swift?

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui

Change the label of a button in swift

hello, i want to make the rectangle of a button changes its color when clicked.
what should i do?

here is my code (im noob)

```
Button(){

}label: {
    Rectangle().fill(.black).frame(width:30, height:30)
}
```

edit: sorry i forgot to mention, it suppose to have more than one color.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following (clicks toggle between the two colors):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var clicked = false
  let color1 = Color.yellow
  let color2 = Color.purple
  
  var body: some View {
    Button() {
      clicked.toggle()
    } label: {
      Rectangle().fill(clicked ? color1 : color2)
    }
    .frame(width: 60, height: 30)
  }
}
```

Comment: nope not really, its going to have more than one colour

Comment: Then adapt the solution for the number of colors needed.  The idea is the same: the `@State` is updated in the button callback and the label callback selects the color based on the state. For example, you could add to the view a `static let colors = [Color.blue, .white, .cyan, .mint, .orange]`, the state becomes `@State private var index = 0` and the button callbacks become `index = (index + 1) % Self.colors.count` and `Rectangle().fill(Self.colors[index])`, respectively.  You get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a set of colors that you have to use or do you want to use a random color on each click?

Here's both options, just uncomment which ever one you want to use:

One uses an array of set colors, the other uses a Color extension to get a random color each time:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var color: Color = .black
    private var colors: [Color] = [.black, .red, .green, .yellow, .cyan]
    
    var body: some View {
        Button() {
            // pick one of the below options and comment out the other.
            
            // this gets a random color each time
            color = Color.random()
            // this gets a random color from the pre set colors array above.
            // you could also keep track of index and loop over the colors in order and start over if needed.
//            if let randomColor = colors.randomElement() {
//                color = randomColor
//            }
        } label: {
            Rectangle().fill(color)
        }
        .frame(width: 60, height: 30)
    }
}

public extension Color {
    static func random() -> Color {
        Color(
            red: .random(in: 0...1),
            green: .random(in: 0...1),
            blue: .random(in: 0...1),
            opacity: 1
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ButtonStyle` `isPressed` for this.

```
      Button(){

      } label: {
        Text("Tap")
          .foregroundColor(.white)
      }
      .buttonStyle(ExampleButtonStyle())
```

```
struct ExampleButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

  func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
      .background {
        Rectangle().fill(configuration.isPressed ? .yellow : .black)
      }
  }
}
```